# fabric js containsPoint function to find if the point is inside the actual content region not in the object bounding rectangle

Tags: jquery, html, fabricjs

In my project i am using a drag and drop feature with images, since i am having many other paths in my canvas i want to know where exactly the image is dropped. I am getting the correct point in the canvas and i am able to find if that point is inside an object using the obj.containsPoint() function, But what i want is similar to one property that exist in fabric js, perPixelTargetFind : true, which enables dragging of objects by clicking on the actual contents not on the bounding regions.
similarly i want to find whether the dropping point is inside the actual content region ?
is this possible ? is there any built in options available ?
Thanks for any help ,

Comment: So you want an option for `containsPoint` to behave the same as `perPixelTargetFind`?

Comment: yes, I am trying to have different clipping regions on the canvas based on some svg paths,after load svg from url, all fabric paths having bounding rectangles with same height and width also all of them are overlapping, so i cant find out on which object the image dropped!.

Comment: `canvas.isTargetTransparent(target, x, y)` should do it